# Installshield exact location for copyfile script

Tags: vbscript, installshield

I am working on installshield setup (Professional). Where I am using a VBscript file for copying files from one folder to another. As a sequence, what should I select from Install UI Sequence and From Install Exec sequence.

I tried it with After movefiles, After Register product etc. It is copying file properly. But when I Installed a new version, an Error related to script is coming.

My Exact settings are [image]

**Error -1720: There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A script required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor script error 2146828218**

Is there anything missing? Or I have to do something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code `-2146828218` is, in hex, error code `800A0046`. Searching for that code indicates this is a permissions issue. Given that, you can either scour your vbscript custom action code for things that might have permissions issues and try to address them directly, or you can try to provide it administrative privileges. If you are trying to modify existing files in a directory such as Program Files (but only doing so when the files are present), that might explain the different behaviors depending on current installation state, and it is likely to simply require additional privileges.

You can try to provide administrative privileges to the action by changing the **In-Script Execution** setting from *Deferred Execution* to *Deferred Execution in System Context*.